# html5lib returns <None>

Tags: python, html5lib

In the first step of `html5lib` tutorial I see pretty confused behavior.

The [docs](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/wiki/UserDocumentation) tells:

```
import html5lib
f = open("mydocument.html")
doc = html5lib.parse(f)
```

> This will return a tree in a custom "simpletree" format.

As file I have a normal html document. But in my case this is:

```
<None>
>>> doc is None
False
```

I believe it is not ok, but I have no idea what happens.

## edit

If I calls `read` method on opened file it is returns file as string:

```
f = open("mydocument.html")
f.read()
# returns string with html
```

And after `doc = html5lib.parse(f)`, `f.read()` returns empty string, like the file the file was already read.

Comment: ofcourse, this is html file copied from login page of redmine=) and I use full path, as `/home/user/file.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the `<None>` doesn't really mean that your document is not parsed, it just means that you document has no name. if you do

  ```
  doc.name = "test"
  print(doc)
  ```

  it should show `<test>`
- `parse` can also take a string as argument, in which case it will load the file for you, no need to open it yourself.
- try `print(doc.toxml())`